# autocomplete jquery struts 2

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, struts2

I have a problem using the autocomplete jquery tool

client side :

```
JQElement.autocomplete({
   source:  function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: jsonAction,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                maxRows: 10,
                startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data , function( item ) {
                        return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.value
                        }
                }));
                //response(data);
            },
            error: function(message, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("une erreur s'est produit lors de la recherche des éléments correspondant à la saisie. Contacter les créateurs du programme");
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
 });
```

the action is called :

```
public String getInsuredNumbers() {
    try {
        String maxRows = request.getParameter("maxRows");
        String startsWith = request.getParameter("startsWith");

        if(maxRows.equals("")) maxRows = "10";
        if(startsWith.equals("")) startsWith = "17";

        String sql = "select assure.ASS_nni, assure.ASS_nom, assure.ASS_prenom from assure where "
                + "assure.ASS_nni like '" + startsWith + "%' limit " + maxRows;
        ResultSet rs = this.getResponse(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            Param p = new Param(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
            data.add(p);
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AutocompleteAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

public List<Param> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

data is an ArrayList of Param

```
public class Param {
  private String value;
  private String label;

  public Param(String value, String label) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
  }

  public String getLabel() {
    return label;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

}

Firebug bug shows me that the json answer is good
the success answer is triggered on client side

However the list under the input appears to be empty

Can you help on that ?

Thank you

Comment: [increasemyacceptance.com](http://increasemyacceptance.com)

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a jsFiddle so we can experiment with and help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I found out why it does show anything. The JSON return is not exactly correct...sure I have my array of data but I have too the success answer from the action... So the question is now : is it possible to send the data only and not the data plus the action answer... ty

Comment: THIS IS EASILY RESOLVED IN FACT :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

On client-side :

```
JQElement.autocomplete({
   source:  function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: jsonAction,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                maxRows: 10,
                startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                var mydata;

                $.map(data, function(item, i) {
                    if(i == "data") {
                        mydata = item;
                    }
                });

                response( $.map( mydata , function( item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                }));
            },
            error: function(message, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("une erreur s'est produit lors de la recherche des éléments correspondant à la saisie. Contacter les créateurs du programme");
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
```